# View changeset locally via visual studio tfs

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, tfs

I want to view all changes locally that have been checked into TFS.

Specifically, I want to take my laptop from work to home, and view all changeset other members checked in, but I cannot connect to my work's VPN tfs server.

Any idea would be very much appreciated.

Comment: This has a lot more to do with how your company exposes its internal servers (aka TFS) to the public internet than it has to do with TFS specifically. If your company offers a VPN connection then you should be able to connect to the VPN... and then connect to TFS just like you were at the office.

Comment: I know that. If I could had done that, I wouldn't have posted question here.

Comment: Alright alright :)
So, do your network admins have TFS NAT'ted out to the public internet? If they have TFS exposed to the public internet you should be able to connect to the public IP address they have exposed from your home internet connection. (I sort of doubt this is how your network is configured) In a nutshell, there is no way you can view the changesets that other members have checked in without connecting to the TFS server.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Git-tf](http://gittf.codeplex.com/) to get a local Git repository (using it for read only). You can then look at the history without TFS connectivity, with Git command line, or visually with a GUI like [Git extensions](https://code.google.com/p/gitextensions/).

First, clone your TFS repo with git-tf.
If you want the entire history, use `--deep`, but it may take a very very long time. You may want to use `--shallow` instead to do a quick clone, but you won't have the entire history, just the history from this day on (like it was the first commit).

```
git tf clone --deep http://myserver:8080/tfs/mycollection $/TeamProjectA/Main
```

Then, whenever you want to update your repo, follow this step

```
git tf fetch --deep
```

It may take some time though (since git-tf is getting every single new commit, and TFS is not optimized for this scenario). You can make a script which run this command every hour.

Using Git will have another advantage : looking at many diff in TFS take some time (since there is a server connection for every file you want to compare with the previous version, and some clicks needed), but in [Git extensions](https://code.google.com/p/gitextensions/) it's really quick, in the same window you can view the history of commits, the current commit files, and the current file diff, instantly (no server connection).

Comment: Thanks! That sounds really promising. I am using TFS 2010, and VS 2012. Does the solution work with them (TFS, VS)? I will try it out. Thanks again.

Comment: If you do this you are basically copying the entire version control repository, including all history, locally. This is almost certainly not feasible unless you're working on a relatively small project with a relatively small number of changesets.

Comment: How to copy/download by date and by branch, if possible?

Comment: @DerekDeida @Pingpong when cloning, you can use `--shallow` to have only the commit from now on, or `--depth=<num>` to start with only the <num> last commits, if needed in your context. Another option to limit number of commits is to change the path you are cloning: instead of cloning `$/TeamProjectA/Main` you can clone only a subdirectory or a branch like `$/TeamProjectA/Main/Src/ComponentC`

Answer (score 0):

You can run the changeset report and save its output. Other than that you are going to need to be able to connect to TFS. It is possible if you have problems with vpn that you might either need to connect via ip address ot check your credential manager to make sure you are setup.

Comment: Thanks! I will search it on how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

If you were using TFS 2013 and a Git repository you would be able to do this.  In the non-git style TFS Source Control (TFVC, the only option before TFS 2013), everything is centralized on the TFS server and without connectivity you are extremely limited.